# How to create toggle switch with an image in html css?

Tags: html, css

How to do a toggle switch with images as in example below? Is there any clear way to achieve this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeFOA.png)

Thanks for any help

Comment: There's lots of stuff out there about creating toggle switches - just search using your title as the search string. To use an image instead of just a color look into background-image as well as background-color. (and filter can even help you decolor your image if you don't already have a black and white version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I've created this quick toggle, just change the images.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
#checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.toggle {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469474968028-56623f02e42e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=874&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px #0000003d;
}

#checkbox:checked + .toggle {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475924156734-496f6cac6ec1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
}

.toggle::before {
  content: "";
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#checkbox:checked + .toggle::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="daynight">
     <label  for="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox">
       <div class="toggle">
         <div class="star1"></div>
         <div class="star2"></div>
       </div>
     </label>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```